# vulkan bdridge betwwen C++ OpenCL and Java GLES on Android

Tags: java, android, c++, opengl-es, vulkan

I would like to be able to share Image betwwen java OpenGL ES and C++ OpenCL. I fact there is no problem sending data from C++ to Java Opengl ES but the opposite way seems not to be working cause of Java OpenGL Context not shared or very slow using MakeCurrent.

So i thought about using Vulkan to make a bridge between both. But it is just an idea. So before starting i think that asking a question about the faesability i not a bad idea.

So the question is :

does anyone could tell me if the bridge option could be possible to implement. And what could be the approch of the problem. Some other idea are of course welcomed ;))

My approch would be to mix java openGL ES and java vulkan and send the buufer adresse of the Image to C++ to preform OpenCL work. So traitement could be done in Opencl then send to OpenGL shader and back to OpenCL.

I know taht it could be easyer to do everithing in C++ directly. But I have a game motor already running in Java and i do not want to rewrite it in C++. Java IDE is very much easyer to practice than C++ code. And i am using VR in JAva already. So it is a lot of work going back to pure C or C++.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Regards herve terrolle from Paris ;))

Comment: Adding Vulkan to the mix will add a good thousand lines of code. Perhaps you should investigate how to share your context first? That is orders of magnitude less work if you can get it to work.

Comment: Yes you are right ;)). But i tried to share the context but i do not succed. And the use of make curent is slow if i must do it per frame. The problem is the context attched to thread. I woul need a context in native but in this case i cannot use JAVA rendering any more. In fact i should do all the rendering in native. But i am using GvrActivity how also setup EGL context at nit(). I try to avoid to much work and sure with vulkan it is a lot to add, i just start to biuld the sample ;)). This EGL context is a paine in the ass. I still do not anderstand why it is so protected ?

Comment: In fact i should find a way to send all OpenGL in native and keep the rest in JAVA. But i have no idea how to make it. There is to much interaction , sensor,touchlistener, piking handled by JAVA and the View. That is my problem. I would need to manage to change too many thing. When i only need to get the context ;)) It is crazy.